NEC 2023 is everywhere now required to have GFCI?
are sections 210 Branch and 422 Appliances the only sections dealing with statements regarding where GFCI is required?
with 210.8 A and B dwelling & non-dwelling it gets pretty specific... bathrooms, garages, rooftops, buffet areas, crawl spaces at or below grade, unfinished basements, outdoors, amd there's more.
with 210.8.D Specific appliances: auto vacuum machines, vending machines, sump pumps, dishwashers, elec ranges, cloth driers, microwave ovens, etc.
so my question becomes now simply tell me where and under what conditions can a non GFCI circuit breaker be used.
side question - wording for AFCI from 210.12 B dwelling units calls out "All 120v single phase 10, 15, 20amps branch circuits supplying outlets or devices installed in any of the following locations... is what you would expect but ends with similar areas.  So with excepting 30A and higher outlets & appliances from AFCI per this wording does this means AFCI is also required everywhere?  so same thing - for < 20A 120v specifically tell me of a location where you don't have to use AFCI now (is there?).

Please take the time to capitalize your sentences. It's a low-effort thing that makes you more readable.

In new construction only? Significant upgrades requiring inspection? Replacing one breaker in your 1962 panel?

Any circuits installed before 2023.  As long as the circuit was in code when installed, it does not need to be upgraded.  Some circuits like bathrooms/kitchens it is highly recommended to use GFCI.  New circuits being installed now might as well to just use GFCI/AFCI circuit breakers for all
